# How to make a component editor perform original handler on double click?

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, delphi-xe7

I've built a custom component editor (`TComponentEditor`) for a custom control of mine. I am implementing the right-click context menu, which means by default, double-clicking the control in design-time executes the first of the context menu items. However, upon double-click, I do not wish for this to happen. I would like the original behavior of creating an `OnClick` event handler.

When overriding the `Edit` procedure of this component editor, I have tried both with and without `inherited`. If I include it, double-clicking executes the first item in the context menu. If I don't include `inherited`, then nothing happens at all when double-clicking the control. Before adding this component editor, the double-click would automatically generate an `OnClick` event handler without any implementation of my own.

```
{ TFontButtonEditor }

type
  TFontButtonEditor = class(TComponentEditor)
  private
    FForm: TfrmFontButtonEditor;
    FBtn: TFontButton;
    procedure ExecEditor;
  protected
    procedure ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); override;
    function GetVerb(Index: Integer): String; override;
    function GetVerbCount: Integer; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AComponent: TComponent; ADesigner: IDesigner); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Edit; override;
  end;

constructor TFontButtonEditor.Create(AComponent: TComponent;
  ADesigner: IDesigner);
begin
  inherited;
  FBtn:= TFontButton(AComponent); //Reference instance of control
  FForm:= TfrmFontButtonEditor.Create(nil); //Create editor form instance
end;

destructor TFontButtonEditor.Destroy;
begin
  FForm.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TFontButtonEditor.Edit;
begin
  //Executed on double-click, but I don't want to...
  //inherited;
end;

procedure TFontButtonEditor.ExecEditor;
begin
  FForm.FFont.Assign(FBtn.Image.Font);
  FForm.ImageChar:= FBtn.Image.Text;
  //More assignments
  case FForm.ShowModal of
    mrOK: begin
      FBtn.Image.Font.Assign(FForm.FFont);
      FBtn.Image.Text:= FForm.ImageChar;
      //More assignments
    end;
    else begin
      //Cancelled
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFontButtonEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
begin
  case Index of
    0: begin
      ExecEditor;
      //Also executed on double-click, don't want it to...
    end;
    1: begin
      MessageDlg('Font Button Control - XXXXX', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TFontButtonEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): String;
begin
  case Index of
    0: Result:= '&Edit Font Button';
    1: Result:= '&About Font Button';
  end;
end;

function TFontButtonEditor.GetVerbCount: Integer;
begin
  Result:= 2;
end;
```

How can I make double-clicking this custom control with a component editor to do the old-fashion `OnClick` event handler rather than trying to execute the component editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descend from [`TDefaultEditor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/DesignEditors.TDefaultEditor) instead of [`TComponentEditor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/DesignEditors.TComponentEditor).

(TDefaultEditor replaces the `Edit` method with your wishes by invoking the `Edit` method of the `OnCreate`, `OnChange` or `OnClick` property, or otherwise the first event property it finds. The Edit method of that property creates the eventhandler in `TMethodProperty.SetValue` with `Designer.CreateMethod` along with several checks concerning inherited forms, existing names, etc...)

Comment: Be aware that deviation from the default designer proceedings might confuse your users.